# REQUEST_URI cannot be detected by Apache

Tags: apache, redirect

I need to intercept with Apache the url request written like this: [www.blog.domain.com](http://www.blog.domain.com)

And then do a permenant redirect with a similar condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^www.blog.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://blog.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Important: This condition will be included in the htaccess file of [www.domain.com](http://www.domain.com)

Answer (score 0):

`REQUEST_URI` does NOT hold the http host named in the request or in the full URL. The [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) clearly shows that `%{REQUEST_URI}` contains the *path component* of the requested URL.

If you want to test against the requested http host you need to use `%{HTTP_HOST}` instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.blog\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://blog.domain.com/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Considering what you said about `%{REQUEST_URI}` above we can simplify this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.blog\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://blog.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]
```

But regardless of all this I am afraid that your initial approach which I modified makes little sense. I would expect that you are actually looking for something like that:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://blog.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Comment: I hope it is clear that the redirect instructions will end up in the .htaccess file of the host www.domain.com. This is because having a wild certificate, third-level www domains are always redirected to the main domain (www.domain.com). So from the main domain I have to redirect to the third one. Therefore what I am trying to do is that when a user types www.blog.domain.com, from the moment he will be diverted to www.domain.com, consequently the .htaccess file in www.domain.com, it will have to redirect him back to https://blog.domain.com.

Comment: What you suggest to do does not work, because by entering your instructions, www.domain.com will also be redirected to https://blog.domain.com. Anyone typing www.domain.com should not be directed to https://blog.domain.com.

Comment: I removed the last option, since it obviously leads to a redirection loop if you implement the rules in a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"). I strongly recommend not doing that, but implementing such general rules in the actual http host configuration instead. That prevents side effects, is more efficient, more secure and _much_ easier to debug and maintain.

Comment: And no, it is _not_ clear what you write above in your first comment. You give a lot of additional information that should have been part of the question itself. From the http server's point of view "blog.domain.com" and "www.domain.com" have nothing to do with each other, _except_ if you explicitly chose a setup where those things are mapped into each other (which you did not say in the question). So please, take a bit of time and revise your question so that your actual setup becomes more clear.

Comment: And no, the lines I posted above will definitely _not_ redirect requests to "www.domain.com" to "blog.domain.com" _Unless you have additional redirection rules in place which you also did not tell us about. Sorry.

Comment: .htaccess or vhost nothing changes. Your instructions do not work in either cases. I am also able to prove it to you. Your first instruction redirects www.domain.com to www.domain.com, blog.domain.com to blog.domain.com but www.blog.domain.com gets redirected to www.domain.com (wrong). Your second and third (which you deleted) instructions redirect www.blog.domain.com and blog.domain.com to www.domain.com (wrong). This is in both .htaccess and vhost. I need www.blog.domain.com to be redirected to blog.domain.com. My question is clear. Thank you. It's better than receiving no answer.

Comment: Sorry, but neither is that somehow magically a "proof" (you just state it), nor is that actually the case. Actually your description does not make much sense. Read again what you write, for example "Your first instruction redirects www.domain.com to www.domain.com" ... _Really?_ No, that is impossible, sorry. The rules can only redirect to "blog.domain.com" because that is the host name that is implemented. If something else happens for you then either you changed the rules or (more likely) you have other, additional rules in place (maybe without knowing that).

Comment: I added a third implementation. Which does something else then what you actually suggested in your question. But which would make actual sense. Have a try with that.